# Try Jupyter loads a blank browser

Tags: try-catch, jupyter

I now have Jupyter installed on Debian 8, but would also like the ability to run it without installing on other machines.

When at tryjupyter.org and I click on the "Try it in your browser" button, the tab is a blank page.  I've tried this in Firefox, Chrome and Chromium.  Any suggestions?  Also happens on my Windows 7 guest in VMWare.

Comment: it's been happening to me too on various machines last few days, i think it's a problem with the site

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you visit `https://try.jupyter.org` instead of `http://try.jupyter.org`. The http link didn't used to work (this has been fixed recently by redirecting to https), but the https link will work.

Comment: Yes, the button was pointing to https://try.jupyter.org.  I verified in my history.

Looks like the "Try it in your browser" URL is working now.